# assert_equal Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have trouble understanding a chunck of code on a book I'm reading.

Here's the code:

```
test "product price must be positive" do
  product = Product.new(:title => "My Book Title", :description => "yyy", :image_url => "zzz.jpg")
  product.price = -1

  assert product.invalid?
  assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", product.errors[:price].join('; ' )

  product.price = 0
  assert product.invalid?

  assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", product.errors[:price].join('; ' )
  product.price = 1
  assert product.valid?
end
```

form the ruby documentation I got:

**assert_equal**(exp, act, msg = nil)

Fails unless exp == act printing the difference between the two, if possible.

am I right to assume that the line:

> assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01" ,

means:

> assert_equal ("must be greater than or equal to 0.01", , )    #with no act or msg.

also, can someone explain what array is the following line using and what for?

> product.errors[:price].join('; ' )

I can't grasp where's the array and what is the author achieving by joining.

Thanks in advance for any information.

The book is:  Agile Web Development with Rails 4th Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full assertion is in one line as follows :

```
 assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01" , product.errors[:price].join('; ' )
```

Here, `exp = "must be greater than or equal to 0.01"` and `act = product.errors[:price].join('; ' )`

`product.errors[:price]` is an array, taking in multiple error messages.

Chaining `.join(';')` to it is making all the error messages joined together with a ';' as a separator.

In this case, there is only one error (`"must be greater than or equal to 0.01"`) and hence the [join method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) is just returning the same value without adding a separator. Hence the assertion should pass.

Example to illustrate the behavior of `join(';')` in this case:

```
> ['a', 'b'].join(';')
=> "a;b" 

> ['a'].join(';')
=> "a"
```

Comment: The errors are an array-type object, so a `join` is required to render them into a string.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I refused to move on on the book because I couldn't understand that piece of code.